# function returns unwanted data

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a JSON file that contains some runners' data.
I'm trying to filter some data by using the following method:

```
performFilterByRunnerName(filterBy: string):IRunners[]{
    return this.runners.filter(x=>x.runnerName=filterBy);
}
```

Part of the HTML is:

```html
<input #filterinputrunner id="runnerFilter" type="text" 
  (change) = "performFilterByRunnerName(filterinputrunner.value)"
  [ngModel]='listRunnerFilter'>
```

And I have a list of `IRunner` type(interface) that holds the runner's data.
When changing the `input` value, what happens is that the `runnerName` field changes for all the `runners` instead of filtering the runners with the input value.
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `return this.runners.filter(x=>x.runnerName==filterBy);`perhaps you miss an =?

Comment: Use comparison instead === rather than = in (x=>x.runnerName=filterBy) which is an assignment.

Comment: you can also check if input is in your runner name or not: ```return(this.runners.filter(x=>x.runnerName.includes(filterBy)));```

Comment: Is your `performFilterByRunnerName` even getting called with `change`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(x=>x.runnerName=filterBy)
```

you want to **compare** not **assign**

```
(x=>x.runnerName==filterBy)
```

should be correct. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

Your filter condition seems to be incorrect. You are assigning (`=`) the `filterBy` property to each of your runners.

What you want is an equality condition (`===`).

`return this.runners.filter(x => x.runnerName === filterBy);`

Answer (score 1):

This line of code highlighted is assigning the value not comparing it.

> return this.runners.filter(x=>**x.runnerName=filterBy**)

you need to do a comparison like:

```
return this.runners.filter(x=>**x.runnerName === filterBy**)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `change` it will not update the filtered results as you type, it will only update it on `blur`. If you want the list to be updated as you type, you should consider using `keyup`.

**`(keyup) = "performFilterByRunnerName(filterinputrunner.value)"`**

Also, filter based on the filter search being included in the result and not the exact string search. That would yield better search results:

```
onFilterChange(filterBy) {
  this.filteredUsers = [...this.users.filter(user => user.name.indexOf(filterBy) > -1)];
}
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rh1wet?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for your ref.